# SAS grouping algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sas

I have the following mock up table

```
#n a b group
1  1 1  1
2  1 2  1
3  2 2  1
4  2 3  1
5  3 4  2
6  3 5  2
7  4 5  2
```

I am using SAS for this problem. In column group, the rows that are interconnected through a and b are grouped. I will try to explain why these rows are in the same group

- row 1 to 2 are in group 2 since they both have a = 1
- row 3 is in group 2 since b = 2 in row 2 and 3 and row 2 is in group 1
- row 3 and 4 are in group 1 since a = 2 in both rows and row 3 is in group 1

The overall logic is that if a row x contains the same value of a or b as row y, row x also belongs to the same group as y is a part of.
Following the same logic, row 5,6 and 7 are in group 2.

Is there any way to make an algorithm to find these groups?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is another observation with a=4 and b=2? Would that mean that there is only one group? or do you only want to process the rows in order A,B so that it will come between rows 6 and 7 and cause there to be four groups?

Comment: Are `a` and `b` always increasing for each successive row? If yes, then Richard's answer will work, but if not then this is a much trickier problem that will involve making multiple passes through your data to identify connected components.

Answer (score 1):

**Case I:**

Grouping defined as to be item linkage within contiguous rows.

Use the LAG function to examine both variables prior values.  Increase the group value if both have changed.  For example

```
group + ( a ne lag(a) and b ne lag(b) );
```

**Case II:**

Grouping determined from pair item slot value linkages over all data.

From [grouping pairs by either key](https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/samples/grouping-pairs-by-either-key.sas)

```
General statement of problem:
-----------------------------
Given: P = p{i} = (p{i,1},p{i,2}), a set of pairs (key1, key2).

Find: The distinct groups, G = g{x}, of P,
      such that each pair p in a group g has this property:

      key1 matches key1 of any other pair in g.
      -or-
      key2 matches key2 of any other pair in g.
```

---

Demonstrates

> … an iterative way using hashes.
>     Two hashes maintain the groupId assigned to each key value.
>     Two additional hashes are used to maintain group mapping paths.
>     When the data can be passed without causing a mapping, then the groups have
>     been fully determined.
>     A final pass is done, at which point the groupIds are assigned to each
>     pair and the data is output to a table.

Comment: This only works if `a` and `b` are both monotonically increasing with respect to `n`. Anything like Tom's example or e.g. `n=8 a=5 b=4` would not be handled correctly.

Comment: My answer does not depend on monoticity, it presumes grouping desired is by row-wise contiguity (within a pair item slot) -- similar in vein to `BY ... NOTSORTED`